# Access standard spreadsheet functions with Sheets API in C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm currently working on a small application with C# and .NET, where I'm trying to mimic a spreadsheet with a graphical interface while simultaneously updating a spreadsheet in Google Drive.

I'll need to use some of the functions and I was trying to find in the documentation if it was possible to access the native functions through the API, but unsuccessfully. I was also trying to do the simple hack of inserting the function as a string directly into a cell, like this (sorry about the usage of a list, I just copied it from another function where I tried filling up multiple cells at the same time),

```
var valuesToAppend = new List<object>() { "=MAX(A1:A5)" };
```

but then I also passed the quotation marks which made it useless.

It might be because it's Saturday and my head haven't worked properly, but I haven't found any solution to this. Is there someone out there who know if I can access the methods easily or if I need to go the long way and implement the functions and do the calculations locally?

Edit: To clarify, what I was hoping to do is insert formulas like =MAX(range), =SUM(range) in a cell from my server through the Sheets API.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access the native functions"? Are you trying to set the value of a cell to a formula (which I believe *is* possible) or compute the value of a formula and get that value in your C# code?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, got caught up in some other stuff. It was the first thing I was looking for, and I completely forgot that they're called formulas (now I really feel dumb). 

I want both really. I want to set the value of a cell the value to a formula (so that the spreadsheet is updated) and then retrieve the calculated value afterwards.

Comment: I believe that's absolutely possible. I haven't used the Sheets API myself yet, but I'm happy to explore it a little. So just to check I understand you correctly, if I take these steps: a) create a spreadsheet manually with some values; b) pass the ID of that spreadsheet to some code; c) (in code) set the value of a cell in a spreadsheet to a formula; d) (in code) retrieve the *visible* (computed) value of that cell, and (say) print it in the console... that would cover everything you're trying to do?

Comment: That would be more or less exactly what I'm looking for. I've starting looking at batch update for adding formula rules to a set of cells, but my initial thought is that it it looks somewhat inefficient way of doing it when the only thing I want is a single cell.

Comment: Great - it would be good to update your question to make it clearer for future readers, but I've added an answer which I've checked does what you want. It does the "update and fetch" in a single request, but I'm assuming you'd be able to work out how to fetch the computed value separately if you need to.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that should be more than enough for me to work with. Seems that programming after a night of heavy drinking really isn't the best thing when trying to learn new things. I was looking at what you did, but for some reason I couldn't connect it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this. You need to specify the `ValueInputOption` as `USERENTERED` for the update request - and you can request to get the content of the cell back (as the computed value) in the response.

So something like:

```
var valueRange = new ValueRange { Values = new[] { new object[] { formula } } };
var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, cell);
request.ValueInputOption = ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
request.IncludeValuesInResponse = true;
request.ResponseValueRenderOption = ResponseValueRenderOptionEnum.UNFORMATTEDVALUE;
var response = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {response.UpdatedData.Values[0][0]}");
```

Here's a complete example containing that code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using static Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Set-up part...
        if (args.Length != 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Required values: <client secrets file> <spreadsheet-ID> <cell> <formula>");
            Console.WriteLine("Example: <secrets.json> <sheet ID> E1 =MAX(A1:D1)");
            return;
        }
        var secretsFile = args[0];
        var spreadsheetId = args[1];
        var cell = args[2];
        var formula = args[3];

        var secrets = File.ReadAllBytes(secretsFile);

        // Don't usually use Task<T>.Result, but this is just a demo console app...
        // we shouldn't have any deadlock worries.
        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new MemoryStream(secrets),
            new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets },
            "user", // Key in file store
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API demo"
        });

        // Interesting bit :)
        var valueRange = new ValueRange { Values = new[] { new object[] { formula } } };
        var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, cell);
        // Pretend we're a user typing in this value...
        request.ValueInputOption = ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
        // Get the computed value back in the response
        request.IncludeValuesInResponse = true;
        // Retrieve the value unformatted (so as a number in the JSON)
        // rather than either the uncomputed value, or the formatted value as a string
        request.ResponseValueRenderOption = ResponseValueRenderOptionEnum.UNFORMATTEDVALUE;
        var response = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {response.UpdatedData.Values[0][0]}");
    }
}
```

Comment: It really irritates me how easy it was, I only had missed the ValueInputOption. Thanks once again!